# AJAX Cross Origin Error

Tags: ajax, mamp

I'm trying to set up my first AJAX dev site on MAMP.  The image below shows my file structure inside a folder htdocs/javascriptAJAX/

[image]

The code in my app.js file is :

```
(function(){

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/data.txt');
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if ((request.readyState===4) && (request.status===200)) {
    console.log(request);
  }
}
request.send();

})();
```

When i look in my console though, I'm getting the standard denial because of cross-origin requests:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///data.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

How do I correct this? Surely if this is being run on MAMP it would have the same server?

Many thanks,

Emily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by the trailing forward slash in the .open() method.

Removing it solved the problem.